# How to toggle Reader view in Firefox using Selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I want to use selenium to open a webpage in firefox, then enter reader view.
Entering reader view is usually done by pressing `ctrl`+`alt`+`r`.
The following python code however only opens the webpage, what am i missing?

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness')
toggle_reader_mode = ActionChains(driver)\
        .key_down(Keys.CONTROL)\
        .key_down(Keys.ALT)\
        .send_keys('R')\
        .key_up(Keys.ALT)\
        .key_up(Keys.CONTROL)
toggle_reader_mode.perform()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK `Actions API` differs from direct user keyboard click, so not all hotkeys can be recognized by browser.

If your goal is to open reader mode, just add `about:reader?url=` to url.

```py
def open_url_in_reader_mode(webdriver, url):
    webdriver.get(f"about:reader?url={url}")

open_url_in_reader_mode(driver, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness')
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. Any tips for getting it to read aloud? Pressing n with send_keys("n") does not seem to work.